# What timing is the access log writtien to

Tags: apache-2.2

Looking at the access log using "tail". At what point does the log get written to by httpd (I'm on CentOS6.3 if it makes a difference) ?

e.g. When the URL is accessed?, when process is finished and the page delivered? Some other timing?

Comment: Run `tail -f` on the log file and make a request. You'll have your answer fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be that hard to check? The log entry can't be written until the request completes (since it includes the status, size of response and may include time taken to handle the request).

If the timestamp is when the request starts and you've got requests taking different times to complete, then the times would be out of sequence.

Comment: Snarkiness isn't really required. It really isn't so easy to check as requests come in over the mobile network and I don't know where the delay is.  So the log is written to after the request is completed. Thank you.